# postgresql window function minimum period to calculate average

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, rolling-computation

i want to calculate rolling average over a rolling period of 252 days but only if 252 days data available in table otherwise null value for rows.
currently i am using this query:
 `SELECT datestamp, symbol, avg(close) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY datestamp ROWS BETWEEN 251 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM daily_prices`.

it is giving avg also if 252 days data not available.
i want acheive result as we get with pandas rolling function by defining min_period value.

Comment: Do you want to convert the short periods to NULL, or filter them out?

Answer (score 0):

*"i want to calculate rolling average over a rolling period of 252 days"*

The clause `ROWS BETWEEN 251 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` doesn't refer to a period of time but to the number of rows in the window and which preceed the current row according to the `ORDER BY datestamp` clause.

I would suggest you a slightly different solution for the window function in order to implement the period of time :

```
SELECT datestamp, symbol, avg(close) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY datestamp RANGE BETWEEN '251 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM daily_prices
```

Then I don't understand in which case you want a null value. In the window of a current row, you will have at least the current row, so that the avg() can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a count over the same window and use it to modify your results.
I used a named window to avoid specifying the same window repeatedly.

```
with daily_prices as (select 1 as symbol, 5 as close, t as datestamp from generate_series(now()-interval '1 year',now(),interval '1 day') f(t))
SELECT 
  datestamp, 
  symbol, 
  case when count(close) OVER w = 252 then 
    avg(close) OVER w 
  end
FROM daily_prices 
window w as (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY datestamp ROWS BETWEEN 251 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```